# Bootstrap #navbar-fixed-top using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do bootstrap navbar-fixed-top with bootstrap.  I am just using Document.body for dynamic padding. It doesn't work. Do anybody now what the cause might be? Please let me know.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="topnavbar">
    <div class="container">Hedaer
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
</nav>
<article>
    <h3>Contents</h3>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes  <br/><br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</article>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    var article = document.createElement("article");

    $(document.body.appendChild(article)).css('padding-top', $('#topnavbar').height() + 70);

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(document.body.appendChild(article)).css('padding-top', $('#topnavbar').height() + 70);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/drg6oe81/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/drg6oe81/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to ask, but you're not adding padding to your article properly. You were using

```
 $(document.body.appendChild(article))
```

This works.

```
$('article')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drg6oe81/5/

If you're asking how to add elements, then you need to put in a list. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/drg6oe81/8/

Answer (score 0):

Use 'body' to apply padding to the body, like:

```
$('body').css('padding-top', $('#topnavbar').height() + 70);
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/drg6oe81/6/)